# SharedPreferences from one Fragment isn't registering data for a Login Activity on another Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, sharedpreferences

I have a fragment called LoginFragment through which a user can Register for the first time by clicking on the Register button. Upon clicking this button a new fragment, called RegisterFragment, opens up where the user chooses and enters a new username and password to be registered. When I run the app and enter the fields under register and select OK, it shows "Saved Info" in the toast like it's supposed to. But when I try logging in using the username and password I registered for, the app doesn't recognize the info and displays the toast "Please check entries and try again" which should only be displayed when the username already exists or the password is incorrect, which in my case is not the case.

Is the SharedPreferences not saving the username and password values because I am working with two different fragments? Any help would be appreciated!

**RegisterFragment.java**

```
   public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

    Button register_btn;
    EditText username_signup_ET, password_signup_ET;

    private  String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private  String KEY_PASSWORD = "pwd";
    private  final String PREFER_NAME = "Registry";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String username;

    //LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    Context context;
    public void myAlertDialog(){
    context = getActivity();
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_fragment_layout, container, false);

        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);;
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


        username_signup_ET = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username_signup_ET);
        password_signup_ET = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.password_signup_ET);

        register_btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
        register_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            String userName = username_signup_ET.getText().toString();
            String password = password_signup_ET.getText().toString();

            if(userName.equals("")||password.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enter Values in all Fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
            register();
            launchLogin();
            }   
            }
        });
        return v;   
    }

    //launch login activity
    public void launchLogin(){
        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
        LoginFragment LG = new LoginFragment();
        FT.addToBackStack("LG");
        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_one_id, LG);
        FT.commit();
    }

    // register your account
            private void register() {
                // prefix the keys with the user name
                editor.putString("userName" + "_" + KEY_UID, username_signup_ET.getText()
                        .toString());
                editor.putString("password" + "_" + KEY_PASSWORD, password_signup_ET.getText()
                        .toString());
                //editor.commit(); // commit the values
                editor.apply();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Info!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }// end of register

}
```

**LoginFragment.java**

```
    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {


    Button login_btn, register_btn;
    EditText username_ET, password_ET;

    private  String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private  String KEY_PASSWORD = "pwd";
    private  final String PREFER_NAME = "Registry";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
     String username;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment_layout, container, false);

        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        username_ET = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username_ET);
        password_ET = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.password_ET);
        login_btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        register_btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.register_btn);


        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // initialize username
                username = username_ET.getText().toString();

                boolean valid = isValid();
                if (valid) {
                    String text = getResources().getString(R.string.logging_in_str);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), text,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (!userExists() | !(passwordCorrect())) {
                        text = getResources().getString(
                                R.string.error_username_str);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), text,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DiaryActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }


                //sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                //get username and password from EditText
                String userName = username_ET.getText().toString();
                String password = password_ET.getText().toString();


                if(username_ET.length() > 0 && password_ET.length() > 0) {
                    String uName = null;
                    String uPassword = null;



                    if (sharedPreferences.contains(userName)) {
                        uName = sharedPreferences.getString("userName", "");

                    }

                    if (sharedPreferences.contains(password)) {
                        uPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");

                    }

                    //start new activity
                    if (userName.equals(uName) && password.equals(uPassword)) {


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You entered: " + uName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DiaryActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
                //String userName = sharedPreferences.getString("userName", "");
                //String pw = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");

                //sharedPreferences.getString("uid", "");
                //sharedPreferences.getString("pwd", "");
            }   
        });

        register_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
                RegisterFragment RG = new RegisterFragment();
                FT.replace(R.id.register_fragment_id, RG);
                FT.commit();
            }   
        });
        return v;
    }

    // getter for the user name
    public  String getUsername() {
        String str = username_ET.getText().toString();
        return str;// returns the user name
    }// end of getUsername()

    private boolean passwordCorrect() {

        // prefix the key with the user name
        if (sharedPreferences.contains(username + "_" + KEY_UID)) {
            String pwd = sharedPreferences.getString(username + "_"
                    + KEY_PASSWORD, "");
            if (pwd.equals(password_ET.getText().toString()))
                return true;
        }
            return false;

    }
    // getter for the user name

    private boolean userExists() {

        // prefix the key with the user name
        if (sharedPreferences.contains(username + "_" + KEY_UID)) {
            String uID = sharedPreferences.getString(username + "_" + KEY_UID,
                    "");
            if (uID.equals(username_ET.getText().toString()))
                return true;
        }

            return false;

    }// end of userExists()

    private boolean isValid() {
        boolean idEmpty = false;
        boolean passEmpty = false;
        if ((username_ET.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
            idEmpty = true;
            String text = getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.error_emptyUsername);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        if ((password_ET.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
            passEmpty = true;
            String text = getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.error_emptyPassword);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        return !(idEmpty | passEmpty);
    }// end of isValid()

}
```

Comment: did u checked your SP file in Android Device Monitor???

Comment: You're mixing up your keys between `"userName" + "_" + KEY_UID` and `"userName"`, and same for password with `KEY_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a different key to get data in LoginFragment. ie
You are trying to access a preference that does not exist. Change your code like below

LoginFragment:

```
private boolean userExists() {

    String uID = sharedPreferences.getString("userName" + "_" + KEY_UID, "");

    return (uID.equals(username_ET.getText().toString()))

}
```

change it for password as well.